# VB.NET How to only show image in visible pictureboxes

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

So I'm creating a program that shows pictures from the internet in pictureboxes that I create on runtime. I create a picturebox for each picture and there are 6 pictureboxes on the screen at a time. But the problem is that as I scroll down more and more pictures are loaded causing the program to take a huge amount of memory. So I'm wondering how I could "de-load" the pictures that have already passed without disposing the pictures so I could go up again and see them without retreiving them again from the webserver (if this is even possible). This should decrease the memory consumption if I'm correct.

I added this picture to maybe help understand the issue.

[image]

Comment: How about a next and previous button and load only 6 at a time?

Comment: Don't store the entire image, resize it so it fits the box and thus requires a lot less memory.

Comment: @DonA yes well that would work but it would be beneficial to be able to just scroll down instead of clicking next and previous I will probably use that if I don't get other replies, Thanks :)

Comment: @HansPassant I'm currently doing this, I scale the pictures to fit the pictureboxes that are 250x250 but when you load 1000+ images it starts to take a lot of memory

Comment: Showing/hiding is easy. Releasing the memory resources allocated to the pictures, isn't too complex either. But you want to release the memory AND not having to load the picture again?! And this is impossible. What you can do is removing pictures (and releasing memory resources) when not visible and loading them again when required; but the pictures have to be store somewhere (in the memory or in the disk from where you have to load them back).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the pictures to the local disk and only load about 100 or so in memory based on where they are scrolled.

As the users scroll you can load the images off the local drive.  If they scroll somewhere that hasn't been loaded in memory yet then show a loading sign while the picture loads from the local drive.

You will be loading/unloading in memory more often, but the max amount loaded will be less.

Comment: This was a good way, Why didn't I think about this, Thank you